# change listener doesnt work in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, listener

I have a dynamic form and i want to add a listener when change a field value, but i couldnt achive to do that. I added a click listener but when i change it to the change it doesnt work.

thanks in advance.

here is the code below :

```
panel = Ext.define('MyApp.view.dynamicform.Form', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
        alias: 'widget.dynamicformform',

        title: title,
        id: 'dynamicform.Form',
        bodyPadding: 5,
        autoScroll: true,
        layout: 'auto',

        defaults: {
            anchor: '100%'
        },
        dockedItems: [],
        items : genItems(storeData),
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function (comp) {
                var element = comp.getEl();
                element.on('change', function(e,el) {
                    alert('blabla')
                });
            }
            },          
            initComponent : function() {
                this.callParent(arguments);
            }

        });
```

when i write click instead of change it works perfectly. I dont get what iam doing wrong.

Comment: What exactly is 'comp' when it gets passed into the afterrender listener. Looking at your code, I would say its the panel itself?

Comment: yeah its is the panel @mindparse

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure there is no change event for a panel in extjs. Normally that event is for inputs like a combo box or a check field.

Comment: What is coming back in genItems() too?

Comment: genItems() generate the comboboxes and the spinners

Comment: when i use click like  element.on('change', function(e,el)  it works perfectly but  element.on('click', function(e,el)  doesnt work @mindparse

Comment: Im confused, you say in your original question that the change event does not fire, but in your last comment you now say change event does work and click doesn't. Which is it?

Comment: sorry for that change event doesnt fire @mindparse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The afterrender event you have added the listener for is purely for the panel component alone. Therefore trying to attach a change event wont work, since you are trying to do this on the panel:

```
afterrender: function (comp) {
                var element = comp.getEl();
                //element is the panel here, not child items such as spinners...
                element.on('change', function(e,el) {
                    alert('blabla')
                });
            }
```

You say the click is working, but I think that's just because you are clicking anywhere on the panel including on the child items you are rendering. Instead, the child items coming back in the genItems() need to contain change event listener configs.

**EDIT**

You could loop through the child items on comp in your afterrender event and for any that are spinners, etc, add the change events that way.

Comment: thanks man. when i get the child elements and add the listener it works.